# How to use Underscore.js as View Engine for Express v3

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, underscore.js, viewengine

There is a question on here answering for v2, but the v3 ExpressJS api is quite different, and uses a totally different layout system. Does anyone have any experience using Underscore.js (if needed with Consolidate.js) as the main view engine for an Express v3 app with the ability to use master layouts?

I've got it as the main view engine but no layouts work (it just prints out the single html file)

Comment: Could you link to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Express 3.x [removes support for layout and partials](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x#view-system-changes). IF you need to do the same thing you used to do, you can always use "EJS" template engine which is basically the same used by underscore and compliment it wit [express-partials](https://github.com/publicclass/express-partials) plug in.